# Saving variable value outside of python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python, been coding in school for about a year now, but I like to code when I get bored. I have made two programs but both are useless as I have to input each value of the variables every time I start it up. Is there anyway I can save the value of a variable externally so when it loads it will open up the file and assign each variable?

Comment: Sure - save it as a settings file and load the settings on startup. See the configparser module, https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `pickle` module for that purpose:

```
l =[1,2,3,4,5]
import pickle
pickle.dump(l,open("mydata","wb"))
```

and for getting your variable back:

```
import pickle
l = pickle.load(open("mydata","rb"))
```

If you have many variables to save, consider embedding them in a dictionary for instance.

Comment: ... with the proviso that pickle is proprietary, ie not really readable by anything other than Python, where configparser or json or yaml may be a bit easier for an end user to modify.

Answer (score 1):

Yo can use the `shelve` module its pretty simple it puts all variables into a dictionary then when your file reopens you can make shelve set the variables back. Here is a good [example](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/110586/rockpaperscissorsv2-follow-up-advanced) of using the shelve module.

Answer (score 0):

To save data to a file, you could use

```
filehandle = open(filename, 'w')
filehandle.write(string)
filehandle.close()
```

Preferred in Python is

```
with open(filename, 'w') as filehandle:
   filehandle.write(string)
```

because the file will be closed upon exiting the `with` block even if the block exits with an error, and without requiring the programmer to remember to close the file.

Load the values back in with `filehandle.readline()` or `readlines()`.

You can also use the Python libraries `json` or `csv` to facilitate moving data into and out of files. If you have no need to inspect or modify the data in the file using another program (e.g. Notepad++ or MS Excel), you might prefer `pickle` or `shelve`.

Comment: Good concept, easily read, a more experienced type concept +1